# Auto layout issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have the following auto layout constraints on the root view of a view controller :

```
(lldb) po [superview constraints]
<__NSArrayM 0x9e65ba0>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67d10 H:[HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67ce0 H:|-(0)-[HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67cb0 V:|-(0)-[HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67c80 H:|-(0)-[RadialGradientView:0x9e685c0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67c50 V:[RadialGradientView:0x9e685c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67c20 H:[RadialGradientView:0x9e685c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9e69040 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e67bf0 V:[HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0]-(0)-[RadialGradientView:0x9e685c0]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10c89830 HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0.height == UIView:0x9e69040.height + 35>
)
```

And when I add the height constraint (the last one), I get an autolayout ambiguous layout error :

```
2013-10-16 16:18:43.121 Application[26038:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb016da0 V:|-(0)-[HeaderView:0xb0192a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb018130 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb016d40 V:[RadialGradientView:0xb0176b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb018130 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb016ce0 V:[HeaderView:0xb0192a0]-(0)-[RadialGradientView:0xb0176b0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb00c3f0 HeaderView:0xb0192a0.height == UIView:0xb018130.height + 35>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb016ce0 V:[HeaderView:0xb0192a0]-(0)-[RadialGradientView:0xb0176b0]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

RadialGradientView is a subclass of UIView that is only overriding the drawRect: method.
The HeaderView is also a subclass of UIView with the following code :

```
@implementation HeaderView
{
    NSLayoutConstraint  * heightConstraint;
}

static UINib * headerViewNib = nil;

- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (![[self subviews] count])
    {
        if (headerViewNib == nil)
            headerViewNib = [UINib frameworkNibWithNibName: @"HeaderView"];

        SMDFHeaderView * headerView = [[headerViewNib instantiateWithOwner: nil options: nil] lastObject];

        [headerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
        [self removeConstraints: [self constraints]];

        return headerView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (!heightConstraint)
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [super layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    if (!heightConstraint)
    {
        UIView * superview = [self superview];
        heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier: 1.0 constant: 35.0];
        [superview addConstraint: heightConstraint];
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

/* Tried that, but it does not change anything.
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return CGSizeMake([[super superview] frame].size.width, 35);
}*/

@end
```

PS : The issue does not seems to be related to the nib replacement trick, even if i comment the awakeAfterUsingCoder method, it does the same thing.

Comment: And if you don't add the height constraint ? Do you have any code for your constraint (to provide with your question), or do you set them in Interface Builder?

Comment: I updated the question, with the code that is adding the height constraint. ALL the other constraints are configured in auto layout (the height one is also configured in autolayout with the new xcode 5 placeholder option "remove at build time")

Comment: Looking at your existing constraints, you have already effectively defined `@"V:|[HeaderView][RadialGradientView]|"`. But you're then trying to add another that says `HeaderView:0x9e6a1b0.height == UIView:0x9e69040.height + 35` clearly cannot be satisfied, too. Can we step back and can you describe what UI you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see why these constraints would be incompatible. 1st I want HeaderView to stick to the top of the screen, 2nd. I want to bind the top of the RadialGradientView to the bottom of the HeaderView, and 3rd I want to bind the bottom of the RadialGradientView to the bottom of the superview

Comment: So why the height + 35 thing? You can't fit a view inside its superview and also make the view 35 points larger than it.

Comment: This is not what i'm doing. By combining the height constraints with the others constraints it should give me something like : "V:|[HeaderView(=35)][RadialGradientView]|"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood how this line works:

```
heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier: 1.0 constant: 35.0];
```

What this is doing is making `self` equal to the height of `superview`, multiplied by 1, plus 35. This means you're asking the subview to be 35 points taller than the superview, and also, elsewhere, asking the subview to fit into the superview. That can't work.

To constrain a view to a particular height, you need to use something like this:

```
heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributenNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1.0 constant: 35.0];
```

This just constrains a view to a specific height.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i found this line of code in another post, i assume that i copied a mistake, and i thought it was the appropriate syntax to define the height of a view :( Thanks a lot.